# How can I upload a video of my solution?

Tags: discussion

How do I post a video of an animation produced by code to the main site? Here's a minimal example:

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[x + t], {x, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 10, .01}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create your gif as:

```
myVideo = Animate[Plot[Sin[x + t], {x, 0, 5}], {t, 0, 10, .01}];
```

Then

```
Export[(filepath here.../myVideo.gif, myVideo, "GIF"]
```

[image]

Then in StackExchange click the teeny image icon on the bar above the text window and ***Browse*** and ***Paste*** myVideo.gif

Comment: Thank you very much sir